# Get values from textfile with C#

Tags: c#

I've got a textfile which contains the following data:

```
name = Very well sir
age = 23
profile = none
birthday= germany
manufacturer = Me
```

And I want to get the profile, birthday and manufacturer value but can't seem to get it right. I succeded including the file into my program but there it stops. I just can't figure out how I will clean the textfile up.

Here's my current code: http://sv.paidpaste.com/HrQXbg

Comment: what do you mean "clean the textfile up" ? Clear all content of the file?

Comment: Remove everything but the pieces I want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var data = File
            .ReadAllLines("test.txt")
            .Select(x => x.Split('='))
            .Where(x => x.Length > 1)
            .ToDictionary(x => x[0].Trim(), x => x[1]);

        Console.WriteLine("profile: {0}", data["profile"]);
        Console.WriteLine("birthday: {0}", data["birthday"]);
        Console.WriteLine("manufacturer: {0}", data["manufacturer"]);
    }
}
```

Comment: I know this is elegant, but i still struggle with LINQ syntax

Comment: I get "The given key was not present in the dictionary." from this solution.

Comment: @Victor, you might have whitespaces in your file. I've updated my answer to add a `.Trim()` in the `ToDictionary` extension method on the key which should remove those spaces. Also make sure that your file contains a line with the given key.

Comment: @Darin - yes I do need to learn - currently learning objective-c and I only have so much space in my brain, my C# knowledge is stuck in .NET2

Comment: What if file contains duplicated KEYS? How to prevent "an item with the same key has already been added" error? I want get only first item (ignoring repeated ones), or repeated item edits last added... How can I just prevent this error? (just KEY are repeated, each one has different (or not!) values)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest instead of using ReadToEnd, reading each line and doing a string.Split('=') and then a string.Trim() on each line text.  You should be left with 2 values per line, the first being the key and the second, the value.

For example, in your reading loop:

```
List<string[]> myList = new List<string[]>();
string[] splits = nextLine.Split('=');
if (splits.Length == 2)
    myList.Add(splits);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to split into lines first and then split the lines:

```
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filePath);
string line;
while(null != (line=reader.Read())
{
    string[] splitLine = strLines.Split('='); 
    //Code to find specific items based on splitLine[0] - Example
    //TODO: Need a check for splitLine length
    case(splitLine[0].ToLower().Trim())
    {
        case "age": { age = int.Parse(splitLine[1]);
    }
}

reader.Dispose();
```

This should make a good start for you.